# Finding a second linearly independent solution of a differential equation with polynomial coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve this problem:

$(x^2-x+1) \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - (x^2+x)\frac{dy}{dx} + (x+1)y = 0$

Given that $y = x$ is one solution, find a second linearly independent solution of this equation.

We haven't learned how to do this in class yet, so I'd really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction by letting me know what formulas I need to know.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

$$(x^2-x+1) \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - (x^2+x)\frac{dy}{dx} + (x+1)y = 0$$
Since you know a particular solution $y_1(x)=x$ use the method of reduction of order :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_of_order

In the present case, change of function 
$$y(x)=y_1(x)u(x)=xu$$
$y'=xu'+u$

$y''=xu''+2u'$

$(x^2-x+1)(xu''+2u') - (x^2+x)(xu'+u) + (x+1)xu = 0$

After simplification

$x(x^2-x+1)u''+(-x^3+x^2-2x+2)u' = 0$

Let $u'=v$

$$x(x^2-x+1)v'+(-x^3+x^2-2x+2)v = 0$$
This is a first order separable ODE. The solution is :
$$v=c_1\frac{x^2-x+1}{x^2}e^x$$
$$u=c_1\int \frac{x^2-x+1}{x^2}e^x dx = c_1\frac{x-1}{x}e^x+c_2$$
$$y=c_1(x-1)e^x+c_2 x$$